# Azure AD B2C user name recovery

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using username for the identity provider for local account. 
When an user forget their username, is there a out-of-box policy that handle the username recovery? Or I have to implement it my own?

If I implement my own, as sign-in policy doesn't have UI customization that I will not be able to add a link for "For get your username" to redirect the user to my code to retrieve their username. Is there a way adding links on the Sign-In page?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box policy for forgotten username. It seems a nice feature though. But I anyway enforce usage of e-mail as username. And frankly, the way to implement this is a bit of a tricky.

You can first get (and confirm) users e-mail address which is registered with the AAD B2C. You have to send him/her an e-mail with a code to make sure that he/she owns the e-mail. Once you get e-mail confirmation, you can query the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) for the [list of users and search for the provided e-mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers).

As for providing link - you can have fully [customized "Sign-in or sign-up" policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool), where you can put the link. You need to use the special `sign-in or sign-up` policy, because currently it is the only one that allows for full user experience customisation.

Comment: I tried the "Sign-in or sign-up" policy where I have the control of UI. As a note that the "Sign-Up" policy also support UI customization as well. Sing-In is the only policy doesn't support. It seems I have to use Graph API calls. Thanks for the info!